# HTML that will render correctly in Outlook 2007/2010

Tags: html, css, outlook-2010

I currently use the following HTML to render the image shown below. This however does not work in Outlook as background images are not supported. I have been tipped to use tables to render elements correctly in outlook, but have no idea how to go about this. 200 bounty to the person  who provides the html that will render the image below correctly in Outlook 2007/2010"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Render this</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        div, p {
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
            font-family: Helvetica;
            font-size:14px;
            color:#000;
            font-weight:bold;
        }
        div.box {
            padding:15px;
            width:272px;
            height:155px;
            border:2px solid #000;
            background-color:rgb(255,232,0);
        }
        div.box div.inner {
            height:100%;
            background:url("https://s3.amazonaws.com/signoffmainbucket/8CA8EC1A-C1C5-4390-9FC4-649648AA26C8.jpg") bottom right no-repeat;
        }
        p.name {
            margin-bottom:65px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="inner">
            <p class="name">John</p>
            <p>XYZ Company</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Render this</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        p {
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
            font-family: Helvetica;
            font-size:14px;
            color:#000;
            font-weight:bold;
        }
        table {
            padding:15px;
            width:272px;
            height:155px;
            border:2px solid #000;
            background-color: #fee800;
        }
        p.name {
            margin-bottom:65px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<tr><td>John Smith</td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td><p>XYZ Company</p></td><td><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/signoffmainbucket/8CA8EC1A-C1C5-4390-9FC4-649648AA26C8.jpg" /></td></tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: TO be on the safe side I would use tables in html email like I did in the example above.  Here is a link to allowed tags in html email: http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Comment: +1 for tables (never thought I'd say that).  Sadly email clients don't like divs.

Comment: I'd also suggest using inline CSS. Contents of html head will most probably be ignored in most webmail clients since the webapp has its own. I think Mailchimp provides an online parser that will convert the stylesheet to inline, since it would be pretty awkward to write longer HTML with inline styles.

Answer (score 2):

For emailer You should have to use table and don't use CSS in head or different CSS. Try to use  and inline CSS.

```
<table bgcolor="#fee800" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="272" height="155" style="border: 2px solid #000; padding: 15px;">
    <tr>
        <td><font face="Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif" style="font-size: 14px;"><b>John</b></font></td><td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><font face="Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif" style="font-size: 14px;"><b>XYZ Company</b></font></td><td><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/signoffmainbucket/8CA8EC1A-C1C5-4390-9FC4-649648AA26C8.jpg" alt="" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```